# How to access model in Laravel Orchestra Testbench

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

Am writing test cases for my Laravel package; it creates Model classes dynamically.

I can see the models are created like;

**`...\vendor\orchestra\testbench\fixture\app\Admin.php`**

But when I try to use the model in my tests;

**`\App\Admin::first();`**

I get the following error

**`Error: Class 'App\Admin' not found`**

How can I access the Model?

Comment: You have incorrect namespace there. \App\Admin points to app/Admin.php file. What's the namespace for that admin.php file?

Comment: Am using namespace App since the Models are actually generated into the app directory

Comment: Ok. Have you tried running composer dumpautoload?

Comment: What is the root namespace for `vendor\orchestra` and/or/following `vendor\orchestra/testbench/fixture` ?